# Image Background Subtraction using EmguCv

Tags: image-processing, emgucv, background-subtraction

How can I implement background subtraction to a static picture taken from a webcam?
I've read some post that says to take a look at the example "Motion Detection" of EmguCV

would it be still applicable if I used it in an image?

Example:

[image: example pic]

(Sorry for poor English)

Comment: Background subtraction is normally for video data, where some parts of the scene are relatively static (background) and other parts are moving (foreground). With a still image, there is no information about which is background and which is foreground - this is subjective. Maybe it would be better to look at segmentation instead.

Comment: thanks for your time @RogerRowland just wondering will this technique http://www.oliveragustin.com/background-subtraction-in-c/ be applicable in my situation?

Comment: It's worth looking at but not for your example image because it has poor colour separation. You may be better off with greyscale conversion then thresholding, then maybe edge detection and contour tracing - there are many ways to tackle it so perhaps pick something and try it first, then show us what happens.